# ASP.NET Repeater - Display Databound in HeaderTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater I want to add a title to in the HeaderTemplate from my database

This is my code so far

```
<asp:Repeater ID="topicView" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TopicName")%></h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostBody")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But nothing is displaying in my header. I heard that you can't use databinder in the header, so could anyone recommend how to do this?

this is my CS code

```
    string topic = Request.QueryString["topicid"].ToString();

    // Define the select statement.
    // All information is needed
    string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM PostView WHERE TopicID ='" + topic + "'";

    // Define the ADO.NET Objects
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader postView = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    topicView.DataSource = postView;
    topicView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to bind to the data source, just bind to a simple property of the page.  Use this in the HeaderTemplate:

```
<h1><%# TopicName %></h1>
```

Then add TopicName as a public property to the code-behind.

```
public string TopicName { get; set; }
```

Then set it when you run the query:

```
TopicName = Request.QueryString["topicid"].ToString();
```

*Side Note*

Not sure if you're aware, but you should be careful of SQL injection.  Instead of injecting the query string directly into your SQL query, it's a good idea to use

```
string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM PostView WHERE TopicID ='{0}';
```

Then add the topic to your SqlCommand as a parameter.